# Magento: Paypal is taking shipping address as default instead of billing address

Tags: php, mysql, magento, paypal, e-commerce

I am using "PayPal Website Payments Standard" in my magento based e-commerce site. At the time of checkout if user eneters separate billing and shipping address and goes to paypal site for payment, then paypal shows shipping address as default along with credit card fields. I want to show billing as default there, instead of shipping.

I have removed this (line:238) `$request['address_override'] = 1;` from this file `` `/app/code/local/Mage/Paypal/Api/Standard.php ``

PayPal takes shipping as default always, if so why? they should take billing, because on paypal page user is making payment.

Please advise, how I can pass billing as default instead of shipping?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php

change

$address = $isOrderVirtual ? $order->getBillingAddress() : $order->getShippingAddress();
if ($isOrderVirtual) {
$api->setNoShipping(true);
} elseif ($address->validate()) {
$api->setAddress($address);
}

to

$address =$order->getBillingAddress();
if ($address->validate())
{
$api->setAddress($address);
}

http://blog.muabana2z.com/?p=70
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solution, this is fixed but why it was passing shipping address, didn't understand? what is isOrderVirtual in code? Could you please help me to understand it?

Comment: @Prashant: isOrderVirtual is, for example, an order with downloadable products